# Centering a list item in an unordered list

Tags: html, css

I've been bashing my head against a wall for too long trying to figure this one out.

I'm building a responsive site for my blog. The navbar is composed of an `<ul>` with 6 `<li>`'s. 5 of them display on a full-size screen. The navicon appears and other list items disappear when the screen is scaled down to mobile size. For some reason I can't get the navicon(hamburger icon) to appear in the center of the screen. I'm trying to avoid centering it using position: relative.

```css
/*Reponsive CSS*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

#navbar nav a {
 display: none;
}

#navbar nav a.menu-icon {
 display: block;
 font-size: 35px;
 padding: 30px 30px;
}

#navbar nav a.menu-icon:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}


}
```

```html
<aside>
 <div id="navbar">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="blank.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="blank.html">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="blank.html">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="blank.html">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</a></li><!--On a mobile device this is the only list item displaying -->
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</aside>
```

[image: current version]

Comment: Before scaling down the `<li>` items are styled to `float: left`. All list items are set to `display: none` after scaling down, does the `float: left` still apply to them even though they are set to `display: none` after the scale down?

Comment: `float: left` does apply to them even if also `display: none` but doesn't have any useful meaning. Items that are `display: none`, and their children, effectively have no impact on the rest of the document.

Comment: The hamburger icon is technically text, right? And, at mobiles sizes, its immediate container (the wrapping `a` element) is essentially screen width, yes? So why not `text-align:center` on that `a` element?

Comment: It makes sense but for some reason when I call `text-align: center;` on the a element it still stays to the left. You can see it directly here: http://www.joelbitar.space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can center elements or text nodes by setting `text-align:center;` or you can center block elements by applying `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` on the element itself.

In this case the `<li>` and its `<a>` are spanning the entire width of their parent, its just the text inside the `<a>` that its not centered. So you would have to apply `text-align: center;` to the `.menu-icon` class

```css
/*Reponsive CSS*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

#navbar nav a {
 display: none;
}

#navbar nav a.menu-icon {
    display: block;
    font-size: 35px;
    padding: 30px 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#navbar nav a.menu-icon:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}


}
```

```html
<aside>
 <div id="navbar">
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="blank.html">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="blank.html">Item 3</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="blank.html">Item 4</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="blank.html">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</a></li><!--On a mobile device this is the only list item displaying -->
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: I understand your logic and it appears that <li> and <a> are spanning the entire width of the parent. However, when I apply `text-align: center` on the a it doesnt want to move. Here is the site with all changes updated: http://www.joelbitar.space

Comment: With just the code you provided it seems like the `<a>` is spanning the entire width, but the image looks styled differently. You should use the developer tools of the browser you are using to inspect whether that is true in your page. If the `<a>` bounding box is spanning only the width of the &#9776; character. Its possible that your elements have `float: left` in that case specify `float:none;` and `text-align: center;` on the `<li>` containing the icon. Look [this](https://jsfiddle.net/92357qpu/) example.

Comment: Just tried it in your site with FF developers tools. `float: none;` does the trick. Also, if you want to center several elements use `float:none; display: inline-block` on the element and `text-align: center;` on the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center;`, but will need to target the list item rather than the anchor tag.  This will also center it between the right most side of the ordered list and the right side of the page.  To offset this you can set the margin on the right side of the icon to offset the width.

Something like this

HTML:

```
<li class="center"><a href="#" class="menu-icon">&#9776;</a></li>
```

CSS

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Edit: After looking at the site, it looks like the line `aside nav ul li { float: left; }`in your main CSS file is over riding the menu icon in the responsive design and forcing it to pull left.  If you remove this line it messes up the whole nav bar so you may consider putting a media query on it at a min 500px (if this is your break point) like this:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    aside nav ul li { float: left; }
}
```

With this you would not need the CSS code given above and can center the icon with a good old fashioned `margin: 0 auto;` in your responsive design section.

```
 .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Be sure to keep `class="center"` targeting your list item.
Hope this works :-).

Comment: That didn't work :P Something must be preventing it from getting centered. The site is joelbitar.space if you have a moment to check it out

Comment: Thanks for you response, much appreciated! Thank you for helping me out :) indeed it did work